# Arrays in Java - Core Java

Tags: java, arrays

In This Question A value is "everywhere" in an array if for every pair of adjacent elements in the array, at least one of the pair is that value. Return true if the given value is everywhere in the array.

`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3}, 1) → true,coz 1 is present in(1,2) and (1,3)`
`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3}, 2) → false,coz 2 is in (1,2) but not in (1,3)`
`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3, 4}, 1) → false,coz 1 is present in 2 pairs (1,2) and (1,3) but 4 is not having a pair of 1`

My Partial working code is below,could you help me out with this problem,stuck up for a long time.

**::Code::**

```
public boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int val) {    
    boolean flag = false;    
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){    
      for(int j=i+2;j<nums.length;j++){    
            if(nums[i] == nums[j]){    
                 flag = true;    
            }    
      }    
    }      
  return flag;     
}
```

Result expected:

```
                           `Expected` `This` `Run`
```

`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3}, 1) → true true OK`
`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3}, 2) → false true X`
`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3, 4}, 1) → false true X`

Comment: case 2 and Case 3 are failing

Comment: @Deepak: Why are they failing?

Comment: looks suspiciously like the Homework tag should be here.

Comment: You don't need to nest for loops for this. Break down the problem. First try to enumerate through the pairs you are considering and doing a System.out.println to see that you are considering the right pairs. Even tiny problems can be taken step by step.

Comment: You don't have "partial working code", you just threw enough code together to try to get us to write it for you.  Obviously a solution which doesn't even make use of `val` couldn't possibly be correct, and you know that.

Comment: @Mark,i dont know how to consider/compare val with an element in each adjacent pairs,

Comment: @Mark Peters, @EnarbenTane, who cares if it's homework? Are you getting mugged? He's asking for some help. Help however you see fit: code, advice on code, pseudo-code, or whatever.

Comment: @Yar,Thanks for that small sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int val) {    

        // use i+=2 to get start index of pair.
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i+=2) {

                // other index in the pair.
                int j = i + 1;

                // make sure the other index really exists.
                if(j < nums.length) { 

                        // if it exists..and val is not equal to 
                        // either in the pair..return false.
                        if(nums[i] != val && nums[j] != val) {
                                return false;
                        }       
                } else {
                        // no pair..one element case.
                        // return true if that element is val..else return false.
                        return nums[i] == val; 
                }       
        }

        // array has no unpaired element..and all pairs have val.
        return true;     
}
```

Comment: @codaddict,i have one question,what the exception scenario isEverywhere({3}, 1) → true false X

Comment: @Deepak: ` isEverywhere({3}, 1)` returns `false` as expected as there is no `1`. Is that not you want?

Comment: yes,correct,probably i need to check my test cases once,Thanks once again,sorry for the trouble,@coaddict

Comment: @Deepak: what about a case such as isEverywhere({1, 3, 4, 1}, 1) If I'm not mistaken this would be expected to return false, but this code would return true. This is because it would only check (1, 3) and (4, 1) isn't the pair (3, 4) considered?

Comment: @shaded,only the adjacency pairs are considered and will return true.@codaddict is correct,i just checked the algorithm i have last clarification,why have u  `return nums[i] == val;`

Comment: @Deepak: Let's say there are odd number of elements in the array. Then the last element will be unpaired. If all the pair(s) before this last element are valid pairs then the entire validity of array depends on this last element. If the last element == val then we need to return true else we need to return false and this is done by `return nums[i] == val;` which is short for `if(nums[i] == val){ return true; } else{ return false;}`

Comment: @codaddict,sorry to come back where r u handling this case in your code.`isEverywhere({1, 2, 1, 3}, 1) → true`.coz i dont see you are checking for `1 in {1,2}` and `1 in {1,3}`,Please comment

Comment: ` if(nums[i] != val && nums[j] != val)` checks to see if `1` is **absent** in the pair. If it's absent I return false. In your case both pairs have 1 so you can see a `return true;` at the end of the function which handles this case.

Comment: @codaddict,cool,thats what i was wondering,thx once again for all your impeccable help...

Answer (score 2):

The key is

> for every pair of adjacent elements in the array

Print out `i` and `j` before `if(nums[i] == nums[j])` and you'd see what's going on.

For an array of length 2, you need (0, 1), for array of length 3, you need (0, 1), (1, 2), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You never use val in your code
Try figuring out the logic for that first

And this can be done with a single loop, try to figure out how you would as a person apply an algorithm, then code it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because the flag does not turn off in the case that the second loop goes beyond the array length.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IE {
    static boolean isEverywhere(int[] a, int val) {   
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("*** iteration: " + i);
        System.out.println("a[" + (i-1) + "]=" + (i > 0 ? a[i-1] : "n/a"));
        System.out.println("a[" + i + "]=" + a[i]);
        System.out.println("a[" + (i+1) + "]=" + (i < a.length -1 ? a[i+1] : "n/a"));
        if (a[i] != val && (i > 0 ? a[i-1] != val : true) && (i < a.length-1 ? a[i+1] != val : true)) {
          return false;
        }   
      }   
      return true; 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 1, 3};
        System.out.println(isEverywhere(a, 1));
        a = new int[] {1, 2, 1, 3};
        System.out.println(isEverywhere(a, 2));
        a = new int[] {1, 2, 1, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(isEverywhere(a, 1));
    }
}
```

Basically, for a given element in the array, the test fails if the value isn't adjacent, either before or after it.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all, and you shouldn't just be doing his homework for him.

Comment: he didn't say it was homework did he? and yes it does work for the given input (now that i edited it).

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but if the length of the array is odd, check that the last value equals the target val

```
...
    if( !(nums.length % 2) == 0 ){
       if( nums[length-1] != val){
          return false;
       }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I did mine by simply counting if there are spaces:
Here it is in it's simple glory:

```
public boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int val) {
    //Create an int to count the number of spaces between each instance of val.
    int counter = 0;
    //Create a for loop that checks val;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
      //If the number at iteration i != val;
      if (nums[i] != val)
      {
        //We increment the counter by one.
        counter++;
      }
      //If the number does equal val, we put the counter back to 0;
      else
      {
        counter = 0;
      }
      //If the counter is greater than or equal to two,
      //We know that there is a space of more than 2, and so
      //We return false;
      if (counter >= 2)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    //Return true if not false;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int val) {
  for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-2;i++){
    if(nums[i]!=val&&nums[i+1]!=val){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```